# Select INNER JOIN mysql DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I want to select database with condition but not working.

I have this query :

```
 SELECT c.*
      ,s.*
      ,f.*
      ,count(c.id) as instock_count
      ,totals.orders_total
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(c.sku SEPARATOR '<br/>') AS sku
  FROM produse_com c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * , SUM(stoc) as stoc_sum
                FROM stocuri_mentor 
                GROUP BY sku ) s 
      ON c.sku = s.sku
  INNER JOIN (SELECT count(id) as orders_total, id_comanda 
               FROM produse_com 
               WHERE NOT ridicat = 'Da'
                GROUP BY id_comanda ) totals
     ON totals.id_comanda = c.id_comanda 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT data_add, status, id_comanda
                FROM comenzi 
                  WHERE NOT (status = 'Impachetat' OR status = 'Stornat' OR status = 'Anulat')
                  ) f
     ON f.id_comanda = c.id_comanda
  WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty
  GROUP BY c.id_comanda
  HAVING instock_count = orders_total
```

The issue is I have a condition `WHERE NOT ridicat = 'Da'`
But the result contain all result with `ridicat = 'Da'`

**EDIT :**
If I remove this query `INNER JOIN (SELECT * ,SUM(stoc) as stoc_sum FROM stocuri_mentor GROUP BY sku ) s ON c.nume_produs = s.sku` AND `WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty` the result is OK

EDIT 2 : SOLUTION = add 1 more condition  `WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty AND ridicat <> 'Da'`

Comment: What if you try `WHERE ridicat <> 'Da'`

Comment: I try but is the same result. Thanks

Comment: My suggestion: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Try to disambiguate it as in : `WHERE NOT produse_com.ridicat = 'Da'`

Comment: i try with `produse_com.ridicat = 'Da'` is the same result.

Comment: I have a good result but is necesary to remove `INNER JOIN (SELECT * ,SUM(stoc) as stoc_sum 
                FROM stocuri_mentor GROUP BY 
                 sku ) s
     ON c.nume_produs = s.sku` AND `WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty`

Comment: This sis weird, then what if you delay it to be the last inner join? `ON f.id_comanda = c.id_comanda` 
`INNER JOIN (SELECT * , SUM(stoc) as stoc_sum ...`

Comment: I fix the issue , i put i more WHERE condition. `WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty AND ridicat <> 'Da'`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this query.

```
 SELECT count(id) as orders_total, id_comanda,  ridicat
                   FROM produse_com 
                   WHERE ridicat != 'Da'
                    GROUP BY id_comanda;
```

Comment: The same result.